# How to make an action button which takes user to Facebook app in iOS?

Tags: ios

I've tried to use the code below but it keeps taking the user to show the  website and I need it to take them to a application on the iPhone, ipad and ipod!

```
- (IBAction)fbIconGo:(id)sender {

    NSURL *fbURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https:facebook.com/numberHERE"];
    // check if app is installed
    if ( ! [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbURL] ) {
        // if we get here, we can't open the FB app.
        fbURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https:facebook.com/NUMBER HERE"];; // direct URL on FB website to open in safari
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbURL];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Facebook app from other app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725815/open-facebook-app-from-other-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URLs should be changed to use the URL schemes instead , Look at these posts for the complete details,

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

[Open a facebook link by native Facebook app on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416338/open-a-facebook-link-by-native-facebook-app-on-ios)

If you are trying to navigate to a page or a profile , the address  should be as follows,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<id>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: I put the number in after NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://<insert function here>"]; "insert function here" and it only takes me to Facebook not the fan page of the app!

Comment: Should be something like  fb://profile/number , if you want to open a page or a profile

Answer (score 2):

You can do with:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<id>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

**[Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook)**

fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile

fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list

fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list (NOTE: there appears to be a bug with this URL. The Notifications page opens. However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the Facebook app)

fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed

fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page

fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list

fb://notes – Open Facebook app to the Notes page

fb://albums – Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Apple URL schemes` to communicate with other apps. Read DOCS [*Communicating With Other Apps*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18)

TO open facebook app use `fb:` URL scheme; i.e.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://https:facebook.com/NUMBER HERE"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```